# How to get specific category names from yaml file?

Tags: c++, parsing, yaml, yaml-cpp

I am using c++ and have a [yaml](http://yaml.org/) file that looks like this:

```
Food:
  Apple:
    - Type: grannysmith
  BellPepper:
    - Type: Red
    - Type: Green
  Sandwich:
    - Type: Ham
```

I need to parse it so that I get a string vector listing only the food names:
`output: "Apple", "BellPepper","Sandwich"`

My code looks like this so far:

```
YAML::Node node = YAML::LoadFile(configYamlPath)["Food"];    
std::vector<std::string> items;    
for (YAML::Node n : node){    
    items.push_back(n.as<std::string>());    
}
```

How would I go about getting those specific keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, `node` is a YAML map.  When you iterate over a YAML map, you get back  `std::pair<YAML::Node, YAML::Node>`, which are key, value pairs.  So, you want:

```
for (auto n : node) {
    YAML::Node &key = p.first;
    // Do something with the key here
}
```

(In actuality, the value returned by dereferencing the iterators is a type that inherits both from `YAML::Node` and `std::pair<YAML::Node, YAML::Node>`, which is why your current code doesn't fail to compile.  But that is an implementation detail.)